# Errors related to the use of wrapperDll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wrapper

We have developed a DLL in C # (managed code) that will be deployed in a C ++ project (unmanaged code).

To communicate unmanaged code written in c ++ with the dll, we used the notion of wrapperDLL.

On the development machine, we were able to correctly compile and run the deployment project.

By launching the application outside the development machine , it works on some PC but does not work on others.

there or it does not work, I get an error with the number 140001 which prevents the execution of my program. If I put in comment the instructions using the wrapperDll there is no longer a problem.

I think the error is related to a lack of windows pack or something like that .

What do you think?

NB: DLL PROJECT IS DEVELOPED IN VS2010

```
  DEPLOYMENT PROJECT IS DEVELOPED IN VS2005

  WRAPPERDLL PROJECT IS DEVELOPED IN VS2005
```

Answer (score -1):

people who faces such problem.

the solution consist of building wrapper dll on release mode instead of debug mode